# First repeated string java

Tags: java, string

OK, i know this question was asked many times here, but i still don't get it, how to find the first repeated character in a string ?
I did something which was close, but it gave me all repeated characters instead of only the first one.
Here's what i did :

```
private static void stringChar(){
    String s = "sababa";
    int count = 0;
    char c[] = s.toCharArray();

    System.out.println("Duplicate characters are :");

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
       for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++){
           if(c[i] == c[j]) {
               System.out.println(c[j]);
               count++;
               break;
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to break the outer loop if you have already found the repeating character.

```
boolean found = false;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++){
       if(c[i] == c[j]) {
           System.out.println(c[j]);
           found = true;
           break;
       }
   }
   if (found) {
       break;
   }
}
```

If you want the count of it

```
int count = 0;
char repeatingChar = '0'; //dummy to overcome compiler warning
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
   for(int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++){
       if(c[i] == c[j]) {
           repeatingChar = c[j];
           count++;
       }
   }
   if (count > 0) {
       System.out.println("Repeating char is " + repeatingChar + ". Occurred " + count + " times");
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: And how can i solve the problem without using nested for loop ?
There must be some way to do it or with 1 for loop or with 2 separated for loops.

Comment: @JohnMason You can use a map or a list as shown by Tim Biegeleisen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

One quick and dirty (yet effective) approach which comes to mind is to maintain a map whose keys are the characters.  In this case, we don't even need a formal map, because we can use an integer array which maps to the underlying ASCII values of the characters.

The basic idea here is to walk down the string, and check the array if we have seen it before.  If so, then print that character and exit.

```
int[] nums = new int[128];    // assuming only basic ASCII characters
String str = "stuff";
for (int i=0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
int index = str.charAt(i);
    if (nums[index] != 0) {
        System.out.println("The first repeated character is: " + str.charAt(i));
        break;
    }
    ++nums[index];
}
```

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

The first repeated char is one you have seen before as you iterate the chars in the string. You can keep track of the first time you see a char with a Boolean array. The array is indexed with the char value. Java automatically "widens" char to int. So, for each char, check if it's been seen before and if not, mark that it has been seen.

```
String s = "sababa";
boolean[] seenChars = new boolean[Character.MAX_VALUE + 1]; // initialized to all false.
for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
    if (Character.isSurrogate(c)) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No first char seen before seeing a surrogate. This algorithm doesn't work for codepoints needing surrogates in UTF-16.");
    if (seenChars[c]) {
        System.out.println("First repeated char is: " + c);
        break;  
    }
    seenChars[c] = true;
}
```

You might notice that I've been saying char instead of character. Character is not a well-defined term. Java's text datatypes use the UTF-16 encoding of the [Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/nameslist/index.html) character set. Some Unicode codepoints require two [UTF-16](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-1) code units (`char`), which are sometimes called surrogate pairs. Since they are not all unique as individual chars, the algorithm doesn't work if they are present.  For example, try `String s = "sababa";` (You can also write it as "sab\uD83D\uDEB2aba".) The answer would be "a", again. But now try `String s = "sababa";` (You can also write it as "sab\uD83D\uDEB2\uD83D\uDEB6aba".) The answer should still be "a" but the algorithm would say "\uD83D" (which of course can't be displayed because it is only part of a codepoint).

Comment: How can i do it with HashSet ?

Comment: @JohnMason use `HashSet<Character>` or `HashSet<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Short and Simple >**

```
void findFirstDupChar() {
        String s = "google";
        Integer dupIndex = s.length() - 1;
        boolean isDuplicateExists = false;
        Map<Character, Integer> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        char[] words = s.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            Integer index = map.put(words[i], i);
            if (index != null) {
                if (index < dupIndex) {
                    dupIndex = index;
                    isDuplicateExists = true;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(isDuplicateExists ? words[dupIndex] + ", index=" + dupIndex : "No duplicateds found");
    }
```

*This will print output as following >*
g, index=0